# read txt file where the same variables are listed in multiple columns using sas

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS. I'm trying to read a txt file where the same variables are listed in multiple columns. [image]

The first variable is the date. The second one is time, and the last one is Blood Glucose.  Thanks a lot for your kindness and help.

Sincerely

Wilson

Comment: Does you data file really use only 7 characters for the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data can be read using a [list `input` statement](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n0lrz3gb7m9e4rn137op544ddg0v.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) with the `:` (format modifier) and `@@` (line hold) features specified.

**glucose-readings.txt** (data file)

```
01jan16 14:46  89   03jan16 11:27 103   04jan16 09:40  99
05jan16 09:46 105   11jan16 10:58 108   13jan16 10:32 109
14jan16 10:49  90   18jan16 09:32 110   25jan16 10:37 100
```

Sample program

```
data want;
  infile "c:\temp\glucose-readings.txt";

  input 
    datepart :date9.
    timepart :time5.
    glucose
  @@;

  datetime = dhms(datepart,0,0,timepart);

  format 
    datepart date9.
    timepart time5.
    datetime datetime19.
    glucose 3.
  ;
;

proc print; run;
```

[image]

From the documentation [**INPUT Statement: List**](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n0lrz3gb7m9e4rn137op544ddg0v.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

> **:**
>   ... For a numeric variable, this format modifier reads the value from the next non-blank column until the pointer reaches the next blank column or the end of the data line, whichever comes first.
>   ...
>   **@@**
>   holds an input record for the execution of the next INPUT statement across iterations of the DATA step. This line-hold specifier is called double trailing @.
>   ...
>   **Tip** The double trailing @ is useful when each input line contains values for several observations.

Be sure to read the documentation, that is were you will find detailed explanations and useful examples.

Comment: If you like puns, the syntax could be called 'clenched'

Comment: Thank you @Richard for your detailed explanation. The code worked.